# XPath query not working for this table

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack

I have many tables in this format:

```
 <table class="DataRows" frame="myFrames" rules="Standard" width="100%">

  <colgroup><col width="70" align="CENTER">
  <col width="200" align="LEFT">
  <col width="80" align="LEFT">
  <col align="LEFT">
  <col align="RIGHT">

  </colgroup><thead>

  <col width="70" align="CENTER">
  <col width="200" align="LEFT">
  <col width="80" align="LEFT">
  <col align="LEFT">
  <col align="RIGHT">

  <thead>

  <tr>
    <td valign="TOP"><span class="classicBold"> 20 </span> Kg.
    <td class="BOLD" valign="TOP" nowrap="">
      PA Passion Foods Inc.
    <td class="BOLD">Fax:
    <td>
      222-555666
    <td class="BOLD">
      Processed foods and juices

  <tr>
    <td><a target="_blank" href="">See on Map </a>
    <td>
      120 NW 157TH AVE 
    <td class="BOLD">Warehouse Hours:
    <td colspan="2">


  <tr>
    <td>
    <td><span class="BOLD">
      Jacksonville,
      </span>
      FL 300000
    <td class="BOLD">Url:
    <td colspan="2">
      <a target="_blank" href="">PA Passion</a>
      &nbsp&nbsp
      <span class="BOLD">E-mail:</span>
      zoro@xyz.com

  <tr>
    <td>
    <td class="REDBOLD" colspan="4">


  <tr>
    <td>
    <td colspan="4" align="LEFT">Franchisee for:<span class="BOLD">
 Nutrella


</span>
  <tr>
    <td>
    <td colspan="4" align="LEFT">Franchisee for:<span class="BOLD">
APPLE Foods, Constants
</span>
  <tr>
    <td>
    <td colspan="4" align="LEFT"><span class="BOLD">

</span>

  <tr>
    <td>
    <td colspan="4" align="LEFT">We service:<span class="BOLD">
All occasions and hospitality services
</span>

  <tr>
    <td>
    <td colspan="4" align="LEFT">We sell :<span class="BOLD">
----
</span>

</td></td></tr></td></td></tr></td></td></tr></td></td></tr></td></td></tr></td></td></tr></td></td></td></td></tr></td></td></td></td></tr></td></td></td></td></td></tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

I am using HtmlAgilityPack to loop thru each of the tables using this code

```
foreach (HtmlNode node in htmlAgilityPackDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[contains(@class,'DataRows')]"))
{

}
```

This gives me the entire node for each iteration one of which is the table as above. I tried to access the company name in each iteration using the code below.

```
string str= node.ChildNodes.Descendants() .SelectSingleNode("//td[@class='BOLD']").InnerText
```

but all I got was the company name of the first table for every table that is extracted in the loop. How do I get the next company name and address when I go thru each table in the loop?

Comment: `//` always start from the root element. use `.` for current context for example `".//td[@class='BOLD']"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common mistake when one trying to do a relative XPath starting with `//` axis. Despite you're calling `SelectSingleNode()` from `node` variable, the XPath is still considered global, which mean it is relative to the root element of the XML. That's why you always get the same element every time, it is the first matched element in the entire XML.

To make the XPath scope local within current `node` element, simply put a single dot (`.`) at the beginning of the XPath  :

```
string str = node.SelectSingleNode(".//td[@class='BOLD']")
                 .InnerText;
```

Comment: Thanks. I seem to have missed an important part when asking the question. Your solution worked for me for getting name. I also wanted the company address. Should I ask the missed part in a separate question or would you be able to answer it here itself? I've added the missed part here. Thanks.

Comment: How would you identify the address node? Is it `<td>` node right before the 4th `<td class="BOLD">`? If it is, you can try : `"(.//td[@class='BOLD'])[4]/preceding-sibling::td"`

Comment: If above doesn't work, I'd suggest to post a separate question and explain what you expect to get for the address given that sample `<table>`, and maybe how you would identify the element in plain words...

Comment: @user20358 turns out `<td>`s are overlapping instead of siblings, so above won't work. Anyway, answer from @decoherence in your new post looks good enough..

Comment: yes. I tried it and it works even if I use the same in a loop without using a table reference

Answer (score 0):

```
node.SelectSingleNode(By.Xpath(.//td[@class='BOLD'])).Innertext
```

This might work.
As said in a comment, using HAP should XPath used as an "extension" from former xpath start with "."- current node if i remember correctly

Comment: By.Xpath... cant find 'By' does this need some other reference?

Comment: SelectSingleNodes("Xpath").InnerText should do